# how do i replace exact phrases in c# string.replace

Tags: c#, string, replace

I am trying to ensure that a list of phrases start on their own line by finding them and replacing them with \n + the phrase. eg

```
your name: joe    your age: 28
```

becomes

```
my name: joe  
your age: 28
```

I have a file with phrases that i pull and loop through and do the replace. Except as there are 2 words in some phrases i use \b to signify where the phrase starts and ends.

This doesn't seem to work, anybody know why?

example - String is 'Name: xxxxxx' does not get edited.

```
output = output.Replace('\b' + "Name" + '\b', "match");
```

Comment: It looks like you're mixing up string replacement `string.Replace` and regular expression replacement `Regex.Replace`

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhhh, also im leaving out the @ at start of match string

Comment: please put an answer to question

Comment: Still not working;
for (int headerNo=0; headerNo<headersArray.Length; headerNo++)
                    {
                        string searchPhrase = "\b" + PhraseArray[headerNo] + "\b";
                        string newPhrase = "match";
                        output = Regex.Replace(output, searchPhrase, newPhrase, RegexOptions.None | RegexOptions.Multiline);
                    }

Comment: got it - needed @ in front of both regex elements, i only had it infront of one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it

```
for (int headerNo=0; headerNo<headersArray.Length; headerNo++) 
{ 
    string searchPhrase = @"\b" + PhraseArray[headerNo] + @"\b"; 
    string newPhrase = "match"; 
    output = Regex.Replace(output, searchPhrase, newPhrase); }
```

Comment: apologies for late addition, thought i posted this but page error'd

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions, accounts for any number of words with any number of spaces:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Regex re = new Regex("(?<key>\\w+(\\b\\s+\\w+)*)\\s*:\\s*(?<value>\\w+)");
MatchCollection mc = re.Matches("your name: joe    your age: 28 ");

foreach (Match m in mc) {
    string key = m.Groups("key").Value;
    string value = m.Groups("value").Value;

    //accumulate into a list, but I'll just write to console
    Console.WriteLine(key + " : " + value);
}
```

Here is some explanation:

- Suppose what you want to the left of the colon (:) is called a **key**, and what is to the right - a **value**.
- These key/value pairs are separated by at least once space. Because of this, value has be exactly one word (otherwise we'd have ambiguity).

The above regular expression uses named groups, to make code more readable.

Comment: I dont know the values 28 or joe so i need to work only with the 'my name' and 'your age'

Comment: @Fearghal: Check the above code - I don't have values `28` or `joe` hardcoded either, you can feed any string to it, to be parsed as a set of key,value pairs.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, misread it. MatchCollection mc = re.Matches("your name: joe    your age: 28 "); is the example string?

Comment: @Fearghal: This can be any string, I included yours as an example, yes.

Answer (score -1):

Following the example you can do that :

```
output = output.Replace("your", "\nyour");
```

Comment: this will not work. the 'your' is an example, what if i have 2 search pharases like CPU and CPU Price, it will mess up and find CPU twice. i need to use \b